# Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/<package>

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile

when build a dockerfile.

```
FROM ruby:latest
MAINTAINER ...
```

I receive some info:

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ruby
bfe1e909440a: Download complete 
33a372e3ad95: Download complete 
1230b07f5c40: Download complete 
0ebd84a329dd: Download complete 
...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/ruby
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/ruby
```

I try with run in console 'docker pull ruby' , it through the same error.

Is it a problem of docker server?

Comment: Are you using a caching repository? or a proxy server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Probably have some kind of `connection issue`. I get that when I'm using free (unreliable) proxy servers.

You can also try to restart your aws instance and check again.

Comment: Currently I think not using proxy. It just an aws instance. and I deploy it by elastic beantalk. How can I fix that. Could you  intruct more detail

Comment: First try to pull another image like `docker pull debian:jessie` , to see if you still have the issue.

Comment: It still bug: Tag jessie not found in repository docker.io/library/debian. I try another instance it work fine. Dont know what happen, so crazy =]

Comment: I still think there is a connection problem for that exact instance.

Comment: Maybe, AWS instance connection have some problem. After restart It work fine now. Thanks a lot Farhad. Life is still beautiful, because of some kindly people like you ^^

Comment: Happy to help, Please accept the answer so we can help others too.